What possible reason is there for including this bit about the isosceles triangle? (Gauss contest)
The following problem appeared in the 2016 Gauss Contest (Grade 8):
In the diagram, $\triangle PQR$ is right-angled. Point $S$ lies on $PR$ so that $\triangle QRS$ is equilateral and $\triangle PQS$ is isosceles with $PS$ = $QS$. The measure of $\angle QPR$ is?

I deduced that the angle measured $30^{\circ}$.
Part of the question seems unnecessary:

$\triangle PQS$ is isosceles with $PS$ = $QS$.

What possible reason is there for including this bit about the isosceles triangle?  It seems unnecessary for solving the problem.

True, it is unnecessary.  I surmise that the problem composer's intent is to either include it as a red herring, or to have the problem solver ignore that $~\angle QRP~$ is $~60^\circ,~$ and compute $~\angle QPR~$ as arcsin$(1/2).$

Yes, what you are saying is true:
$\triangle QRS$ is equilateral so $\angle QRS = 60^\circ$.
$\triangle PQR$ is right angled at $Q$ so $\angle QPR + \angle QRP = 90^\circ$.
Therefore, $\angle QPR = 90^\circ - 60^\circ = 30^\circ$.
Note the above solution ignores the fact that $\triangle PQS$ is isosceles.

The statement does not say which angle is the right angle (although the diagram does). If you imagine the right angle is at $P$ and if you permit "point $S$ lies on $PR$" to mean that $S$ is on the line $PR$ rather than the segment, then you can make the equilateral triangle larger than $\triangle PQR$ and end with $\angle QPR$ being $90^{\circ}$. But the other triangle being isosceles precludes that.
This is a stretch in more ways than one. But it's maybe an explanation for the relevance of the isosceles triangle in the author's mind.

When the diagram is supplied in the question.. to mention PS=QS is superfluous or repetitive.. even though it is not contradictory. After stating the problem it may have occurred to the problem setter to put in extra explanation/clarification so as to be sure that the problem is fully understood.

You are correct in pointing out that the part of the question:

$∆PQS$ is isosceles with $PS = QS$

is redundant, especially because $∆QRS$ being equilateral spontaneously implies that $S$ is the circumcenter of $∆PQR$, and therefore, $PS = QS$. It isn't a separate condition since it holds true for all configurations when $∆QRS$ is equilateral and $∆PQR$ is right-angled at $Q$, of course.
There is perhaps one reason I can think of that justifies their motif behind including the redundancy, which is either to simply waste the contestants' time or create scenes of ignorance from the contestants' end — just a psychological diversion. After all, it is a timed math contest, so I wouldn't expect the question developers to keep it nice and fair and simple, would you?
